# C#, label ignores parts of the given text

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

i need to put in my label something like "x rub | y%" but label ignores the rest of text after the x.
when the label gets "0" value, it works as i want it to, i.e. "0$. | 0%", but whenever the value isnt 0, it only displays "read_cat"'s value ("2000"). Thank you in advance.

```
System.IO.StreamReader reading2 = File.OpenText("categories\\clothes.txt");
read_cat1 = Convert.ToString(File.ReadAllText("categories\\clothes.txt")); 
clothes_percentage.Text = Convert.ToString(read_cat1) +"$ | "+ 
Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(read_cat1) * 100 / salary, 2))+"%";
reading2.Close();
```

Comment: *label ignores the rest of text* - you've perhaps ended up with an ascii nul (character 0x00) in the label text. Windows controls interpret 0x00 as "end of string" and don't render any text after it. Try `whateverLabel.Text = someString.Replace('\0','.')` and see if your missing text appears

Comment: @Caius Jard , just tried, sadly it doesnt work

Comment: OK, so what's the exact text youre trying to set in your label? We don't have your `clothes.txt` on our computers. Perhaps give it to us as b64 encoded just incase there are some wacky chars in it: `Convert.ToBase64String(yourStrAsByteArray)` and post the result of that into your question

Comment: it says it cant be converted from "string" to "byte[]"

Comment: Yes, you'll need to do e.g. `Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes` to turn the string to a byte array

Comment: it gives me this: MzgzNDINCg==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your file contains a linebreak after the actual value. Use the Trim() method to remove linebreaks and other whitespace from the string you read from the file.

```
string read_cat1 = File.ReadAllText("categories\\clothes.txt"); 
read_cat1 = read_cat1.Trim();
clothes_percentage.Text = read_cat1 + "$ | " + 
    Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(read_cat1) * 100 / salary, 2) +"%";
```